# TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: n

Tags: python

I am new to programming. When I wrote the code, I met one error and I can not understand why it appeared.
This is the code below.

```
class Summator():   
    def transform(self, n):
    return n

    def sum(self, N):
        a = 0
        for i in range(N + 1):
            a += Summator.transform(i)
        return a



class SquareSummator(Summator):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, n):
        return n ** 2


class CubeSummator(Summator):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def transform(self, n):
        return n ** 3
```

This is the error I am getting.

> TypeError: transform() missing 1 required positional argument: 'n'

Comment: well you're calling a classmethod via a class-reference rather than an instance of that class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your code like this:

```
def sum(self, N):
a = 0
for i in range(N + 1):
    a += self.transform(i)
return a
```

As for why your code doesn't work: you're invoking a instance method via a Class name rather than its instance.

Comment: If you could check the tick next to my answer to accept it I'd appreciate that :)